# I want to know how i can set a time limit on my stopwatch

Tags: javascript, html

I have been using the setTimeout and a alert, but noticed the timer still continues when i press "OK" on the alert and it doesn't work for my reset. Meaning when i click reset, the timer won't know that the time has reset and will continue to count onto the alert.

```
<body>

    <div class="class">
        <h2>CSC 131 Attendance Tracker</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="stopwatch">
        <div class="title">
            <h2>KEY:</h2>
            <!-- <input type="text" name="output" id="Key"> -->
            <p><font size="7" id="Key" ></font></p>
            <!-- <button onclick="createKey()">Generate</button> -->
        </div>
        <div class="time">
            <h2>TIME:</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="display">
            <span class="minutes">00:</span><span class="seconds">00:</span><span class="centiseconds">00</span>
        </div>
        <div class="controls">
            <!-- <button onclick = "myFunction(); startTimer();">Start</button> -->
            <button onclick = "createKey(); setTimeout(timesUP(), 299999);" class="start">Start</button>
            <button class="stop">Stop</button>
            <button onclick = "createKey();" class="reset">Reset</button>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script>
        function takeKey(){
            var Input = prompt("");
            if (Input!= null) {
                document.getElementById("takeID").innerHTML = Input;
            }
        }

        function createKey() {
            var x = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 6)
            document.getElementById("Key").innerHTML = x;
        }

        function timesUP() {
            alert('TIMESUP');
        }

        var ss = document.getElementsByClassName('stopwatch');

        [].forEach.call(ss, function (s) {
        var currentTimer = 0,
            interval = 0,
            lastUpdateTime = new Date().getTime(),
            start = s.querySelector('button.start'),
            stop = s.querySelector('button.stop'),
            reset = s.querySelector('button.reset'),
            mins = s.querySelector('span.minutes'),
            secs = s.querySelector('span.seconds'),
            cents = s.querySelector('span.centiseconds');

            start.addEventListener('click', startTimer);
            stop.addEventListener('click', stopTimer);
            reset.addEventListener('click', resetTimer);

        function pad (n) {
            return ('00' + n).substr(-2);
        }

        function update () {
            var now = new Date().getTime(),
                dt = now - lastUpdateTime;

            currentTimer += dt;

            var time = new Date(currentTimer);

            mins.innerHTML = pad(time.getMinutes()) + ":";
            secs.innerHTML = pad(time.getSeconds()) + ":";
            cents.innerHTML = pad(Math.floor(time.getMilliseconds() / 10));

            lastUpdateTime = now;
        }

        function startTimer () {
            if (!interval) {
                lastUpdateTime = new Date().getTime();
                interval = setInterval(update, 1);
            }
        }

        function stopTimer () {
            clearInterval(interval);
            interval = 0;
        }

        function resetTimer () {
            stopTimer();

            currentTimer = 0;

            mins.innerHTML = secs.innerHTML = cents.innerHTML = pad(0);
        }
    });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Why do you have `onclick` functions on the `<button>` and also binding click event listeners on them with JavaScript? The `setTimeout` created by the button's `onclick` can't be cleared or cancelled.

Comment: Basically for the project i am creating the professors UI for attendance sheet. The attendance sheet for the student end would take the key generated by the professors UI and they would submit it with their SID. And the key must have a time limit of 5minutes. So i wanted to add the key function to the start, that way students know, as soon as the professor clicks start the key will be generated and the stopwatch will run at the same time to show that they have 5 minutes.